# Can this solution be simplified this way?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have an exercise which I also have the answer for, but the answer seem very complicated, I am wondering if my simplified solution also is correct, or does it miss something?

the exercise:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\{f_n\}_{n \in
> > \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ that converges
>   $\mu$-ae. to a function $f \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$.(This just
>   means that the function f is also measurable). Assume that there
>   exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and a $C \in \mathbb{R}$, $C>0$, such
>   that $\|f_n-f_N\|\le C$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Show that $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$.

Here is the suggested solution:

[image]

But my idea was juist to do this:

We have that the $f_n$ converge pointwise ae, and fatous lemma holds in this case aswell if the function it converges to is measurable which it is in our case. So:

$\int |f|d\nu=\int \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n| d\nu$, since the integral on a set of measure zero doesnt change the value. Then:

$\le \liminf \int |f_n|d\nu = \liminf \|f_n\|_1 \le \liminf (\|f_N\|+\|f_n-f_N\|_1)$, by the triangle inequaqlity.

$\le\|f_N\|+C<\infty$. Hence f is integrable.

Does this solution also hold? They do alot more work in the suggested solution, but is that work needed?